# How can I use two database connections in node.js? (mysql)

Tags: mysql, node.js, database

I want to make requests for two databases using express and mysql modules and listen on port 8000.

Comment: Can you provide any code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create multiple db connections using mysql node package like:

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({...});
var otherConnection = mysql.createConnection({...});
```

See node-mysql [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#establishing-connections)

createConnection creates a new, separate database connection object on each call.