# Dynamic Database name is not allowing connection for SQL Server from Nodejs

Tags: node.js, sql-server, express

I am trying to connect to SQL Server Database by passing in the database name from the front-end. I tried two options one of the is working and another one is not. Lets say
Method 1: The below method is working:

```
app.post('/getDropDown/crop',async(req,res)=>{   
    let dropdownModel = {}
    await sql.connect(
        `Server=cloud.com,1433;
        Database=${req.params.crop};
        User Id=imuser;Password=abc;
        trustServerCertificate=true`,err=>{
        if (err) console.log(err)
        new sql.Request().query(`
        SELECT DISTINCT TBNAME AS "Experiment", TBYEAR AS "Year", TBFLD_NAME AS "Trait"
        FROM dbo.EXP01 t1
        JOIN dbo.EXP02 t2 ON t1.TBID = t2.TBKEXPT
        JOIN dbo.TRD01 t3 ON t2.TBKTRAIT = t3.TBID`,(err,result)=>{ 
            dropdownModel['Year']= Array.from(new Set(result.recordsets[0].map((item)=>item.Year)))      
            dropdownModel['Trait'] = Array.from(new Set(result.recordsets[0].map((item)=>item.Trait)))
            dropdownModel['Exp'] = Array.from(new Set(result.recordsets[0].map((item)=>item.Experiment)))      
            res.send({"data":dropdownModel})          
        })
    })
})
```

However, I am trying to separate out the connection to a different function or module so that I do not have to write the whole connection string every time.
Method 2: The below method is not working:

```
 function createDB(dname){
    let connection= 
    `Server=cloud.com,1433,
    Database=${dname},
    User Id=imuser,Password=abc,
    trustServerCertificate=true`  
    return connection
}



app.get('/getDropDown/:crop',async(req,res)=>{
    await sql.connect(createDB(`${req.params.crop}`),err=>{
        if (err) console.log(err)
        new sql.Request().query(`
        SELECT DISTINCT TBNAME AS "Experiment", TBYEAR AS "Year", TBFLD_NAME AS "Trait"
        FROM dbo.EXP01 t1
        JOIN dbo.EXP02 t2 ON t1.TBID = t2.TBKEXPT
        JOIN dbo.TRD01 t3 ON t2.TBKTRAIT = t3.TBID`,(err,result)=>{
            console.log(result)
            })
        }
    )
})
```

[I referenced this answer to create Method 2, but has no luck.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52418998/how-to-create-dynamically-database-connection-in-node-js) Any help is appreciated how to separate out the connection string from the service and use it as a function.

Comment: _"Not working"_ is not helping us to help you. Do you get an error message? What is the complete error message - as text, not screenshot(s).

Comment: I will point out that the first "working" example is correctly delimiting the connection string properties with `;` characters and the second "not working" example is incorrectly delimiting the connection string properties with `,` characters. Both examples here are using a string whereas in the other link you reference all examples are using Javascript objects.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Ahhh the semi-colon!!! the nightmare of every programmer. Thank you it worked. In the second option the delimiter was causing the error

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Thank you so much. I appreciate it. I just ignored the `;`