# Connection to multiple databases on different hosts of the same API Rest

Tags: node.js, express

This is my configuration file of my API connections

```
const mysql = require("mysql");

const pool = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit: 10,
  user: user1,
  password: 123456,
  database: database1,
  host: host1.server.com,
  port: 3306,
});

exports.pool = pool;
```

What I need is for my API to connect to more than one server, where the databases are. How can be?

I tried it like this and it didn't work:

```
const mysql = require("mysql");

const pool1 = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit: 10,
  user: user1,
  password: 123456,
  database: database1,
  host: host1.server.com,
  port: 3306,
});

const pool2 = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit: 10,
  user: user2,
  password: 123456,
  database: database2,
  host: host2.server.com,
  port: 3306,
});

exports.pool = { pool1, pool2};
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: What didn't work about it?

Comment: Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45304238/how-can-i-use-two-database-connections-in-node-js-mysql). I believe it may have something to do with connections vs pools.

Comment: This post is about connections, I would like it to be in a Pool.

Comment: Yes, but perhaps pools are the problem. Why not try it with a regular connection and debug from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem.

I wasn't exporting correctly.
Then I fixed it as below, and it worked.

```
module.exports = { pool, pool2 };
```